# Why does an 'IMAP search by header' fail when the header value is given by a variable, not a string?

Tags: python, email, imap, imaplib

I can get the uid of an email that has a certain header value like this:

```
    res, tmp = self.mail.uid('search', None, '(HEADER Message-ID "<123.456.789@localhost>")')
```

Then, tmp becomes

> [b'2993']

But I get that Message-ID value from a file, store the value into a variable(msg_ID), and give the msg_ID variable as an input.

When I try the above one like:

```
tmp = "<123.456.789@localhost>"
res, tmp = self.mail.uid('search', None, '(HEADER Message-ID tmp)')
```

tmp returns an empty list

> [b'']

, which means that it failed to search the target email.

How can I give an appropriate input with a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you're sending the actual string `tmp` - it won't be expanded inside the string magically.

You also lack the other formatting around the string, which should be added to make them identical:

```
'(HEADER Message-ID "' + tmp + '")'
```

That way your strings will actually be identical and it should work as you expect. As your code is written you're just asking for the email with the Message-ID literally set to `tmp`.

Answer (score 0):

I could also figure this out by using

```
res, tmp = self.mail.uid('search', None, '(HEADER Message-ID %s)' %tmp)
```

Comment: Add double-quotes around `%s`: `'(HEADER Message-ID "%s")' % tmp`